# For loop iterating through string and adding/replacing characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I need to write for loop to iterate through a String object (nested within a `String[]` array) to operate on each character within this string with the following criteria.

- first, add a hyphen to the string
- if the character is not a vowel, add this character to the end of the string, and then remove it from the beginning of the string.
- if the character is a vowel, then add "v" to the end of the string.

Every time I have attempted this with various loops and various strategies/implementations, I have somehow ended up with the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Any ideas?

**Update: Here is all of the code. I did not need help with the rest of the program, simply this part. However, I understand that you have to see the system at work.**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class plT
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        String file = "";
        String line = "";

        String[] tempString;
        String transWord = "";                  // final String for output

        int wordTranslatedCount = 0;
        int sentenceTranslatedCount = 0;

        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Pig-Latin translator!");
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name with the sentences you wish to translate");
        file = stdin.nextLine();

        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(file));

        fileScanner.nextLine();
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
        {

            line = fileScanner.nextLine();

            tempString = line.split(" ");

            for (String words : tempString)
            {
                if(isVowel(words.charAt(0)) || Character.isDigit(words.charAt(0)))
                {

                    transWord += words + "-way ";
                    transWord.trim();
                    wordTranslatedCount++;
                }
                else
                {

                    transWord += "-";
                    // for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)

                    transWord += words.substring(1, words.length()) + "-" + words.charAt(0) + "ay ";
                    transWord.trim();
                    wordTranslatedCount++;
                }


            }

            System.out.println("\'" + line + "\' in Pig-Latin is");
            System.out.println("\t" + transWord);
            transWord = "";
            System.out.println();
            sentenceTranslatedCount++;

        }

        System.out.println("Total number of sentences translated: " + sentenceTranslatedCount);
        System.out.println("Total number of words translated: " + wordTranslatedCount);

        fileScanner.close();
        stdin.close();
    }

    public static boolean isVowel (char c)
    {
        return "AEIOUYaeiouy".indexOf(c) != -1;
    }
}
```

Also, here is the example file from which text is being pulled (we are skipping the first line):


2

How are you today

This example has numbers 1234

Comment: It is better to show the code

Comment: @PSR, I have added the relevant code block. Additionally, you can see that I have placed `words.substring(1, words.length())` in as placeholder until I can get a loop that works. I needed this to test that the operations were occurring correctly.

Comment: @user3072758 In what way is that the relevant code? Why are you calling `trim()` and discarding the result? Are you forgetting to assign `transWord` back to an array? What is `transWord`? What output do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: `trim()` is called to cut the space at the end of the string. `transWord` continues containing all of the words that we have operated on thus far and is the final, full string that will be output with all modifications to the user.

Comment: When you call `trim()` it does not operate on the `String` in-place (`String` is immutable). Instead, it returns a new `String` instance. You still haven't given us an example input and (desired) output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the issue is `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, then the only way this is going to occur, is when one of the `words` is an empty String. Knowing this also provides the solution: do something different (`if` \ `else`) when `words` is of length zero to handle the special case differently. This is one way to do this:

```
if (!"".equals(words)) {
  // your logic goes here
}
```

another way, is to simply do this inside the loop (when you have a loop):

```
if ("".equals(words)) continue;
// Then rest of your logic goes here
```

If that is not the case or the issue, then the clue is in the parts of the code you are not showing us (you didn't give us the relevant code after all in that case). Better provide a complete subset of the code that can be used to replicate the problem (testcase), and the complete exception (so we don't even have to try it out ourselves.